# InvalidRequestError on ManyToMany relation with backref

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've problem with SQLAlchemy m2m association. After adding `backref` to my `relationship` association, sqlalchemy throw error.

Models:

```
assoc = Table('foo_bars_assoc', db.metadata,
     Column('foo_id', Integer, ForeignKey('foo.id')),
     Column('bar_id', Integer, ForeignKey('bars.id')),
     PrimaryKeyConstraint('foo_id', 'bar_id', name='foo_bar_assoc_pk')
)


class Foo(db.Model):
    bars = relationship("Bar", secondary="foo_bars_assoc")


class Bar(db.Model):
    value = Column(String, unique=True)
```

I created `get_or_create` util method

```
def get_or_create(**kwargs):
    entity = db.session.query(Bar).filter_by(**kwargs).first()
    if not entity:
        entity = Bar(**kwargs)
        self.db.session.add(entity)
        self.db.session.commit()
    return entity
```

Let's suppose that all bars already exist:

```
for i, bar in enumerate(foo.bars):
    foo.bars[i] = get_or_create(value=bar.value)
```

That method works well, until I add a back reference to m2m relationship.

Error:

```
(psycopg2.IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "bar_value_unique"
```

Can anyone explain what happened here? Why after adding this backref, sqlalchemy is trying to make inserts to database ?

Comment: Can we see your association table? And show us the code that's actually causing the problem. If I understand your post correctly, you've only included the code that works. And your `get_or_create` "util class" is just a function.

Comment: Thank for reply. Association table is very simple so I decided not to paste it into pseudo code. But check edited post. `get_or_create` is a part of DAO in my project. But I changed it for simplicity to method. Error occurs when i add `backref` argument to bars `relationship("Bar", secondary="foo_bars_assoc", backref="foos")`

Comment: Why does your association table have the PrimaryKeyConstraint? Sounds like that's related to the error.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. It should be a *complete* script that we can run to reproduce that exception. Posting just the code that you think causes the issue is not sufficient.